# Socket hang up error not caught in try catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, try-catch

In the production environment, I'm using `node 16.14.2`. The pods are failing due to a `Socket hang-up error`. Although the socket `hang-up error` is not that frequent, I need better error handling for this error.

There is a try-catch block in place for error handling, but it still won't catch socket hang-up errors.

```
export const keepAlive = () => {  
  const keepAliveSettings = {    
    keepAlive: true,    
    maxSockets: config.MAX_SOCKETS,    
    maxFreeSockets: config.MAX_FREE_SOCKETS,    
    timeout: config.SOCKETS_KEEPALIVE,    
    keepAliveTimeout: config.SOCKETS_KEEPALIVE_TTL,  
  };  
  const httpAgent = new Agent(keepAliveAgentSettings);  
  
  // for SSL  
  keepAliveAgentSettings.rejectUnauthorized = false;  
  const httpsAgent = new Agent.HttpsAgent(keepAliveAgentSettings);  
  return {    
       httpsAgent,    
       httpAgent,  
  };
};



// Axios instance with AgentKeepAlive setup.
   export const getAxiosInstance = () => {  
     const webAgent = keepAlive();  
     return axios.create({    
       httpAgent: webAgent.httpAgent,    
       httpsAgent: webAgent.httpsAgent,  
     });
   };

// Inside the function
    try {    
      response = await axiosInstance.get(`${url}${xt}${param}`, { httpsAgent: getHttpsAgent() });  
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error.message")
    }
```

Error Logs:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
} [message]: undefined
```